# How to stop Sapper from scrolling back to top in nested routes?

Tags: scroll, svelte, sapper

The thing is that I have two routes
`/istifta` and `/istifta/edit`

The `/istifta` route displays istiftas (questions) while `/istifta/edit` route opens up a panel for editing questions on the same page due to same `_layout.svelte` file.

The only problem is that when I access `/istifta/edit` from `/istifta`. It not only opens up the editing panel but also scrolls to the top of page. How can I stop this behavior? I want to remain on the same scroll position upon this navigation. The istiftas is a long list. For editing it should remain on the same scroll position. Scrolling to bottom again and again and finding ids is overly complicated for the user.

Please solve this. Specially, **Rich Harris**, if you are reading this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We really should get round to documenting this, but if you add a `sapper-noscroll` attribute to an `<a>` tag, it will prevent that behaviour:

```html
<!-- in src/routes/istifta/index.svelte -->
<a href="istifta/edit" sapper-noscroll>edit</a>
```

Comment: Extremely Helpful.

Comment: Hi, sapper-noscroll not working for me.. I have provided my usage below.. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

"sapper": "^0.27.9"

sapper-noscroll not working for me

blogs
blogs/index.svelte

```
<a sapper-noscroll href="blogs/1">Go to Blog 1</a>
<a sapper-noscroll href="blogs/2">Go to Blog 2</a>
<a sapper-noscroll href="blogs/3">Go to Blog 3</a>
<a sapper-noscroll href="blogs/4">Go to Blog 4</a>
...
...
<a sapper-noscroll href="blogs/100">Go to Blog 100</a>
```

blogs/[slug].svelte

```
<a href="blogs">Go Back to Blogs </a>
<h1> Blog details<h1>
```

still it scrolls to the top when I go back to Blogs page from Blog Details page. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

it's 2020 and it looks like things have changed by one char since Rich's answer.

`sapper-noscroll` didn't work for me, but `sapper:noscroll` did.

[Sapper docs on the subject](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#sapper_noscroll)

Answer (score 0):

This has been changed with the release of SvelteKit

To prevent scrolling on click, it is now `<a href="path" data-sveltekit-noscroll>Path</a>`

Docs:
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options#data-sveltekit-noscroll